# ¿Como visualizar un reporte de crystal reports en una pestaña diferente al de la pagina web en el navegador?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola espero me puedan ayudar ya que no encuentra la manera de poder resolver esto de antemano gracias.

Tengo un formulario con un botón para mi reporte de crystal reports, cuando presiono este botón se carga y visualiza mi reporte en la misma pestaña de mi pagina por lo que mi pagina se pierde y tengo que regresarme a ella con las flechas del navegador después de haber guardado el reporte.

mi pregunta es:

¿Como podría visualizar este reporte en una pestaña diferente a la de mi pagina?

Este es mi código que se encuentra dentro del botón.

```
 DataTable reporte = new DataTable();
 reporte = t.Reportes(id_persona); // Llamado a la capa de transacciones.
 ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();

            rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/Reporte_Persona.rpt"));
            rpt.SetDataSource(reporte);
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();             
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            MemoryStream oStream = new MemoryStream();
            oStream = (MemoryStream)
            rpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);                
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";                           
            Response.BinaryWrite(oStream.ToArray());
            Response.End();
            oStream.Flush();
            oStream.Close();
            oStream.Dispose();
```

Comment: Agrega el codigo que tienes del lado del cliente, en lugar de boton podria ser una referencia asi se abrira un nuevo tab.

Comment: Incluye el código de la página que tiene el botón para indicar a partir de ahí las posibles soluciones de una manera más directa y que puedas escoger lo que te viene mejor.